# Is there a way of using html to embed videos on a Telegram channel?

Tags: html, video, iframe, embed, telegram

I would like to know if there is a away of implementing HTML coding in messages of a Telegram Channel.

I have a telegram channel where i would like to display some videos but instead of uploading them or sending only the link of the video i would like to embed them on messages just like happens with youtube ones.
The embed is just an iframe like in html.

Is there a way? Exists a bot that can do that?
Thank you